# Import csv from Yahoo Finance into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, yahoo-finance

Using [Johnboy's tutorial](http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql) on importing .csv files to MySQL, I tried to make a script that would take exchange rate data from Yahoo finance, and write it to the MySQL database.

```
<?php  

//connect to the database 
$host = "****"
$user = "****"
$password = "****"
$database = "****"
$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password); 
mysql_select_db($database,$connect);

//select the table  
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $symbol = "ZARINR"
    $tag = "l1"
    $file = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=$tag&s='$symbol'=x"; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO ZAR_to_INR(exchange_rate) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                ) 
            "); 
            echo "done";
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

} 

else{
    echo "nope";
}

?>
```

I added the echos in the hope that they'd tell me whether or not the script worked. It doesn't work at all. There are no error messages or anything. When I run the script by opening it in my webhost, it simply does not run.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to make this script work (or even an alternate way of solving the problem).

Comment: try using mysql debugs : `mysql_select_db($database) or die('Cant connect to database');`

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die('query fail : ' . mysql_error());`

Comment: `$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Cant connect to server: ' . mysql_error());`

Comment: Do you have your error reporting enabled so you can see any errors being generated?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I don't. How do I do that?

Comment: @Melon I just tried those, there's still absolutely nothing. I get a blank page when I run the script, even after adding them.

Comment: ofcourse, you hav to check your php error_log

Comment: @Melon It hasn't generated one. Sorry if I come off as a bit dumb, I'm still quite new to PHP.

Comment: Got it. Error reporting wasn't on. Whoops.

Comment: @Melon This was the error i got `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/vol3_1/byethost9.com/b9_14228173/htdocs/CurrencyRetrievalScript.php on line 5
`

Comment: Line 5 has the password on it.

Comment: Never mint that. Semicolons were missing. I got a `query fail : Query was empty` because I didn't have a query.

Comment: @Melon Once I commented out the query, it gave me a success message. However, the MySQL database did not get updated with new data.

Answer (score 1):

try using mysql debugs :

```
mysql_select_db($database) or die('Cant connect to database'); 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('query fail : ' . mysql_error());
$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) 
    or die('Cant connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
```

to find this outputs you need to check your php error_log : [where-does-php-store-the-error-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log)

Comment: `query fail : Query was empty` Is the only error message I get. Which query should I be using?

Comment: It seems to connect to the database and server fine, it even has the header change to the success message, but my MySQL database does not have the data added to it.